# Сохранить view как картинку

Tags: java, android, view

Класс для View:

```
public class MyDrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
.......
   @Override
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
       vectorDrawThread = new VectorDrawThread(getContext(), getHolder());
       vectorDrawThread.start();
   }
.......
}
```

Класс для потока:

```
public class VectorDrawThread extends Thread {
.......
 @Override
 public void run() {
     running = true;
     while (running) {
         Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
         if (canvas != null) {
             try {
               (рисование)
             } finally {
                 surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                 running = false;
             } 
           }
       }
 }
```

Activity:

```
public class WPgen extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_wpgen);
   ....
   Redo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           MyDrawView.vectorDrawThread.run();
         }};
   Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         (КОД)
         }};
   ......
    }
 }
```

XML:

```
...
 <view
  android:id="@+id/ResView"
  class="xxx.yyy.MyDrawView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1" />
...
```

Задача:
По нажатию кнопки Save (где написанно "(КОД)") реализовать сохранение нарисованного на ResView (MyDrawView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло:

```
 Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
 gb = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 gc = new Canvas(gb);
 if (canvas != null) {
     try {
         (рисование на gc, а не на canvas)
         canvas.drawBitmap(gb, 0, 0, null);
     } finally {
         surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
         Log.d("Running?", "false");
     }
```

(gb - Bitmap (который затем был сохранён). gc - Сanvas)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
public static void shareViewWithText(AppCompatActivity activity, View viewToShare) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewToShare.getWidth(), viewToShare.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    viewToShare.draw(canvas);

    saveImageToGallery(activity, bitmap);
}


public static void saveImageToGallery(Activity activity, Bitmap image) {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(), image,
                activity.getString(R.string.app_name),
                null); //todo wtf
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что сохраняется чёное изображение.

Comment: @coopjmz, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20110099/3212712?

Comment: не помогло. По-прежнему чернота.

Comment: @coopjmz, других идей нет(